# Error while reciving image in the application using firebase and flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

whenever I try to build this app and run this app its runs successfully but unable to get images from firebase database and I get this error. i tried to use firebase plugins and checked in the console that the app is been configured or not but the app was connected correctly i can create user and login in the app also able  to upload photo but unable to recive it

```
D/FlutterView(19804): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@daebe54
I/OpenGLRenderer(19804): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer(19804): Swap behavior 1
W/RenderThread(19804): type=1400 audit(0.0:22544): avc: denied { search } for name="kgsl-3d0" dev="sysfs" ino=22816 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_kgsl:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
W/Adreno-ES20(19804): <get_gpu_clk:229>: open failed: errno 13
W/Adreno-EGL(19804): <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:612>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
W/Adreno-EGL(19804): <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:612>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
I/SurfaceView(19804): updateSystemUiVisibility, blackBackground = false, viewVisibility = 0, appBounds = Rect(0, 0 - 720, 1440), mScreenRect = Rect(0, 0 - 720, 1356), surface = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{ff4c83e V.E...... ......ID 0,0-720,1356}
D/FlutterView(19804): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@daebe54
W/1.gpu   (19804): type=1400 audit(0.0:22545): avc: denied { search } for name="kgsl-3d0" dev="sysfs" ino=22816 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_kgsl:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
W/Adreno-ES20(19804): <get_gpu_clk:229>: open failed: errno 13
W/Adreno-EGL(19804): <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:612>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
W/Adreno-EGL(19804): <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:612>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
I/flutter (19804): Image Url: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blog-8c8f3.appspot.com/o/Post%20Image%2F2019-12-31%2003%3A09%3A37.024688.jpg?alt=media&token=0cf6ac7c-a2cd-4e7b-b85c-da21d8f3488c
I/flutter (19804): Length: [Instance of 'Posts'].length

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following assertion was thrown building:[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 22 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.


[38;5;248mEither the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
[39;49m

[38;5;244mWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack[39;49m
[38;5;244m#2      new NetworkImage[39;49m
[38;5;244m#3      new Image.network[39;49m
[38;5;248m#4      _HomePageState.postsUI[39;49m
[38;5;248m#5      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244m#6      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build[39;49m
[38;5;244m...[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following assertion was thrown building:[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 22 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.


[38;5;248mEither the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
[39;49m

[38;5;244mWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack[39;49m
[38;5;244m#2      new NetworkImage[39;49m
[38;5;244m#3      new Image.network[39;49m
[38;5;248m#4      _HomePageState.postsUI[39;49m
[38;5;248m#5      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244m#6      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build[39;49m
[38;5;244m...[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

here is my code link [blog](https://github.com/sadsouler/blog)

Comment: better include some part of your code in question too.

Comment: i linked it at the end

Comment: Please add the part of the code that gives this error

Comment: i have added log file up there `[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following assertion was thrown building:[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 22 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.
`

Comment: At what file are you getting this error? Your git has like 6 or 7 files

Comment: in blog/lib/HomePage.dart

Comment: see I can upload a photo to firebase database and it is uploaded successfully but unable to receive on the homepage

Comment: The URL for the image is not being fetched from Firebase correctly, has the image URL been successfully uploaded to Firebase ?

Comment: Can you print the `postList` images values? For each Post in postList, print the `image` value.

Comment: @AdemirVillenaZevallos it's showing `null`, all the data is being shown except the url, so probably url has not been correctly fetched from Firebase Storage or has not been stored correctly on the Database

Comment: arhaaam patvi yes its been successfully uploaded to firebase

Comment: You can see the correct link to the image as well?

Comment: yes i can see it correctly

Comment: Yes. But I think there is a simpler possibility: When you access the `DATA[individualKey]["images"]`, maybe "images" is not the path to the url image. You can check the correct path at Firebase on web.

Comment: @AdemirVillenaZevallos Yes i figured it out and felt like it was total overkill to pull the repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made an error replace "images" with "image"

```
 DATA[individualKey]["image"],
 DATA[individualKey]["description"],
 DATA[individualKey]["date"],
 DATA[individualKey]["time"],
```

Comment: okay let me try

Comment: @KenKanaki it works I tried it :D

Comment: no not yet my windows beeing updating

Comment: @KenKanaki I meant that I already tested it by downloading your repo from github and making the change works perfectly

Comment: ya its working fine but old post comes first then new post